# Display Alternate text when Distinct occurs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sample data as below:

```
ID          Message
-------------------
1           Car
2           Car
3           Car
4           Boat
5           Train
```

I need help to figure out a query so that when I do a `SELECT DISTINCT ID, Message`, the result will look like:

```
ID          Message
--------------------
Multiple    Car
4           Boat
5           Train
```

Whenever there are duplicate "Message" occur, the query should "group" all of them together and replace the ID with a plain text "Multiple".

(In my actual database, the ID is stored as `nvarchar`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement with `COUNT()` to check for duplicates.  This also means you'll be using `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'Multiple' ELSE MIN(ID) END) ID, Message
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Message
```